# Почему не выводит информацию на монитор LCD 16x2 I2C

Tags: c++

Код:

```
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
    LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd ( 0x27 , 16 , 2 ); 
    void setup () { 
        lcd.begin(16,2);
        lcd.backlight();
    }
    void loop ()
    {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print('ddsad');
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print('hello world');
        delay(10);
    }
```

Схема:

[image: Схема]